# Sublink not working in r webscraping - df comes up with blank cells

Tags: r, dataframe, web-scraping

I have a working code to scrape a webpage and its initial nested link, but I wanted to click the 2nd level to scrape more so I wrote what I thought would the right method based on the success of 1st level. I get no values though, only the headers are present. I would appreciate any advice on this.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

link = "http://ufcstats.com/statistics/events/completed?page=all"
page = read_html(link)

name = page %>% html_nodes(".b-link_style_black") %>% html_text()
name_links <- page %>% html_nodes(".b-link_style_black") %>% html_attr("href")

fight_info = function(name_link) {
  fight_page = read_html(name_link)
  tibble(
    date = fight %>% html_nodes(".b-list__box-list-item:nth-child(1)") %>% html_text(),
      fight_event = fight %>% html_nodes(".b-list__box-list-item:nth-child(1)") %>% html_attr("href"),
        Fighter1 = fight_page %>% html_nodes(".b-fight-details__person-status_style_green+ .b-fight-details__person-text .b-fight-details__person-link") %>% html_text(),
        Fighter2 = fight_page %>% html_nodes(".b-fight-details__person-status_style_gray+ .b-fight-details__person-text .b-fight-details__person-link") %>% html_text(),
        Referee = fight_page %>% html_nodes(".b-fight-details__label+ span") %>% html_text(),
        F1Control = fight_page %>% html_nodes(".b-fight-details__table-col:nth-child(10) .b-fight-details__table-text:nth-child(1)") %>% html_text(),
        F2Control = fight_page %>% html_nodes(".b-fight-details__table-col:nth-child(10) .b-fight-details__table-text+ .b-fight-details__table-text") %>% html_text(),
        F1ControlRD = fight_page %>% html_nodes(".b-fight-details__table-col:nth-child(10) .b-fight-details__table-text:nth-child(1)") %>% html_text(),
        F2ControlRD = fight_page %>% html_nodes(".b-fight-details__table-col:nth-child(10) .b-fight-details__table-text+ .b-fight-details__table-text") %>% html_text(),
        Weightclass = fight_page %>% html_nodes(".b-fight-details__fight-title") %>% html_text()
  ) -> t
  return(t)
}

df <- map_dfr(name_links, fight_info)
```

Comment: You call `get_decisions` in `map_dfr` but your function is called `fight_info`?

Comment: I just fixed it, but received another error, 

"Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") : 
  no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "character"
Called from: xml2::xml_find_all(x, make_selector(css, xpath))"

Comment: ... `fight` should probably be `fight_page`?

Comment: Hmm, I appreciate it. Made the change but then received this error which I'm not sure how to deal with. 

"Error: Tibble columns must have compatible sizes.
* Size 0: Existing data.
* Size 10: Column `F1Control`.
ℹ Only values of size one are recycled.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
Called from: signal_abort(cnd)"

Answer (score 1):

Besides the smaller issues in your code which I already mentioned in the comments one option to achieve your desired result using a somewhat different approach would be to extract the all infos at once via `html_table` and to do some data cleaning afterwards:

The tricky part is to split the cells like `Fighter` which contain two rows for which I use `string::str_split` and to put these rows into different columns for which I make use of `tidyr::unnest_wider`:

```r
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

link = "http://ufcstats.com/statistics/events/completed?page=all"
page = read_html(link)

name = page %>% html_nodes(".b-link_style_black") %>% html_text()
name_links <- page %>% html_nodes(".b-link_style_black") %>% html_attr("href")

get_fight_info = function(name_link) {
  fight_page <- read_html(name_link) 
  
  fight_info <- fight_page %>% html_table() %>% .[[1]]
  fight_info$date <- fight_page %>% html_node(".b-list__box-list-item:nth-child(1)") %>% html_text()
  fight_info$event <- fight_page %>% html_node(".b-list__box-list-item:nth-child(2)") %>% html_text()
  
  fight_info <- fight_info %>% 
    mutate(across(c("Fighter", "Str", "Method"), ~ str_split(.x, "\\n\\n\\s+\\n")),
           date = str_remove(date, "^\\s+Date:\\s+"),
           event = str_remove(event, "^\\s+Location:\\s+"))
  
  fight_info %>% 
    unnest_wider(Fighter, names_sep = "") %>% 
    unnest_wider(Str, names_sep = "") %>% 
    unnest_wider(Method, names_sep = "") %>% 
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ str_remove_all(.x, "\\n") %>% str_trim()))
}

fight_info <- map_dfr(name_links[1:3], get_fight_info)

fight_info
#> # A tibble: 35 x 15
#>    `W/L` Fighter1  Fighter2 Kd    Str1  Str2  Td    Sub   `Weight class` Method1
#>    <chr> <chr>     <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>          <chr>  
#>  1 win   Islam Ma… Thiago … 0   … 61    13    3   … 1   … Lightweight    SUB    
#>  2 win   Miesha T… Marion … 0   … 65    25    3   … 0   … Women's Banta… KO/TKO 
#>  3 win   Mateusz … Jeremy … 0   … 1     0     1   … 1   … Lightweight    SUB    
#>  4 win   Rodolfo … Dustin … 0   … 49    67    3   … 1   … Middleweight   SUB    
#>  5 win   Billy Qu… Gabriel… 1   … 100   57    3   … 1   … Featherweight  KO/TKO 
#>  6 win   Daniel R… Preston… 0   … 45    23    0   … 0   … Welterweight   KO/TKO 
#>  7 win   Amanda L… Montser… 1   … 7     3     0   … 0   … Women's Straw… KO/TKO 
#>  8 win   Sergey M… Khalid … 0   … 50    33    6   … 0   … Bantamweight   U-DEC  
#>  9 win   Malcolm … Francis… 0   … 46    28    2   … 0   … Flyweight      U-DEC  
#> 10 win   Rodrigo … Alan Ba… 0   … 49    60    0   … 0   … Heavyweight    KO/TKO 
#> # … with 25 more rows, and 5 more variables: Method2 <chr>, Round <chr>,
#> #   Time <chr>, date <chr>, event <chr>
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your effort in creating this. I am just having a little trouble understanding some the changes such as the [1:3], and the mutate(across(c("Fighter", "Str", "Method"), ~ str_split(.x, "\\n\\n\\s+\\n")). I tried to add some rows for more specific statistics, and received this error which is why I'm trying to understand these changes:
"Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
ℹ `..1 = across(...)`.
x Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `Total_SigStrike` doesn't exist."

Comment: First. When scraping via html_table the content of cells with two pieces of data, like the fighter names is returned as a concatenated string. Hence, I have had look how to split this string in two pieces and found that the regex `"\\n\\n\\s+\\n"` does a fairly good job. I would suggest to comment out the data cleaning parts to have a look at the returned raw data yourself. Second. If you want to add columns with additional info, then I would suggest to do this is in separate step.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand that, but I am curious as to how to replicate this function, name_links <- page %>% html_nodes(".b-link_style_black") %>% html_attr("href") to go to a subpage of this. As this string pulls up the sublinks of the original page, I want to click each event within these subpages, and I have a common character in '.b-link_style_black' again, would I just indent and paste the same script with relevant values?